# How to check to specific dataframe using all rows and find the differences?

Tags: r

Using a dataframe like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4), num = c(23,42,12,33))
```

and a second one like this:

```
df2 <- data.frame(id = c(1,3,4,2,5), num = c(23,12,33,0,2))
```

How is it possible to compare all rows from the first one with the second one and find which rows doesn't exist in the second one and make the same process to see which rows from the second dataframe doesn't exist in the first one and save the results into two different output?

Example results:

```
df1notexist <- data.frame(id = c(2), num = c(42))

df2notexist <- data.frame(id = c(2,5), num = c(0,2))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `setdiff` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
setdiff(df1, df2)
setdiff(df2, df1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `dplyr`

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
    anti_join(df2)

df2 %>%
   anti_join(df1)
```

return

```r
> df1 %>%
+   anti_join(df2)
Joining, by = c("id", "num")
  id num
1  2  42
```

and

```
> df2 %>%
+   anti_join(df1)
Joining, by = c("id", "num")
  id num
1  2   0
2  5   2
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is base R option using `subset` + `merge`

```
> subset(merge(df1, cbind(df2, f = TRUE), all.x = TRUE), is.na(f), select = -f)
  id num
2  2  42

> subset(merge(df2, cbind(df1, f = TRUE), all.x = TRUE), is.na(f), select = -f)
  id num
2  2   0
5  5   2
```

---

Or, we can use `%in%` + `paste`

```
> df1[!do.call(paste, df1) %in% do.call(paste, df2), ]
  id num
2  2  42

> df2[!do.call(paste, df2) %in% do.call(paste, df1), ]
  id num
4  2   0
5  5   2
```